# Laravel Eloquent and combing data to send to View

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out a way to combine data from two tables into a single variable that I can then send to my view.  I'm using Authority as my authentication bundle and so I have the following tables set up: users, roles, role_user.  I want to get the following data into a single variable.

From the users table:
id, name, email

From the roles table: 
name

The following returns all the user data in the users table:

```
$users = User::all();
```

But, I want to make a chain that can get the related data stored in the roles table? I want all users and all of each users roles together.

And while I can find examples that help get related data for a single record I haven't been able to find any reference to retrieving entire tables with related data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get()
```

Eager loading is what you are looking for, read the docs :)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that, but I didn't have my model setup properly before, which was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what you are after, I think you should make relations with Eloquents methods. But if you are looking for a way to just merge the data returned by two models you could do the following:

```
$users = User::all();
$roles = Roles::all(); 

$array = array_merge($users->toArray(), $roles->toArray());
return Response::json($array);
```

You could make the model calls so that they return exactly what you are after and then merge them together. If you want one Model to return something specific just make a function for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I want to do is get all users with their specific roles so I can send the data to a view. Specifically I'm using the bootstrapper bundle that will let you create a table effortlessly by sending an array to it's table::body($array) function, which makes the code very clean and quick to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like that:

```
$user = User::get();
$roles = Roles::get();

$user .= (object) $roles; //because of that both them are object array and we have to combine them as object array...
```

than you can pass the data to View

```
return View:make('templatefile')//or Redirect to_route whatever
      ->with('user', $user);
```

But the best way is belongs_to in your case. Please read the documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships